# Dynamic Jpanels - Assigning Values to them

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Good day. I have a small code that I am working on which allows me to add JPanels to a panel. I am successfully able to make things work just as I wanted them to be but it left me with 1 problem. How do I assign values to them.

```
package NotificationPush;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.VerticalLayout;

public class NewClass extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    List<JPanel>jps = new ArrayList<JPanel>();
    public NewClass() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 778, 426);
        setLayout(new VerticalLayout());

        JButton addButton = new JButton();
        addButton.setText("Click to add a new Panel");

        JTextField jtf = new JTextField();
        jtf.setText("Add here what you want to see in the button click");

        add(addButton);
        add(jtf);

        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JPanel jp = new JPanel();
                jp.setBackground(Color.red);
                JButton btn = new JButton();
                btn.setText("JButton number "+(jps.size()+1));
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(addButton, "This button has been clicked");
                    }
                });
                jp.add(btn);
                jps.add(jp);
                add(jps.get(jps.size()-1));
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        NewClass jp = new NewClass();
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        JScrollPane scp = new JScrollPane();

        scp.setBounds(10, 101, 742, 276);
        jf.setBounds(100, 100, 778, 426);

        jf.add(scp);
        scp.setViewportView(jp);
        scp.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);

        jf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.show();  
    }

}
```

What I would like to happen is whatever I input into the textbox will be assigned to the new button generated and when I click that button It will respond which what I String I assigned to them. Any Ideas how can I achieve this?

Second, I would like to add a function wherein I can remove the panel after I clicked the button. I have a hunch that I need to assign something to these panels so I can remove them from my Main Panel. Please add a reference on the code if needed. thank you.

Comment: Wrap the `JTextField` and `JButton` into a `JPanel` and add that to your main container. Personally, I'd start by creating another class which maintained the `JTextField` and `JButton` and isolated the functionality to that class, just simpler that way. I'd also consider using a `JTable` :P

Comment: I have been pondering with the topic of custom rendering in JTable but unfortunately I could not understand how it functions. I was able to follow the first few steps but when it goes deeper I constantly get confused. I would appreciate if you could provide me with some easier to understand references that could jumpstart me with working with JTables.

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) are probably the best starting places

Comment: `"Second, I would like to add a function wherein I can remove the panel after I clicked the button."` -- sounds like you want to use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) here, something that would allow you to easily swap components in a container.

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses. It seems the suggestion to create a separate JPanel class was awesome! I was able to get what I was looking for but I will still look into the reference you provided @MadProgrammer. Thank you everyone.